# How to disable transpose shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, high-sierra, preferences

How can I disable the system transpose (Ctrl+T) shortcut?

Note: I'm using a MacBook Pro running High Sierra (10.13.1)

I've tried searching online, stack overflow, etc. and tried everything I could think of, but I haven't been able to find any way to disable the system keyboard shortcuts. For example, Ctrl+T doesn't appear under Preferences > Keyboard. I even tried manually editing `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist`, but it doesn't appear there either.

For reference, here's what my ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist file looks like

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These `emacs`-style shortcuts -- like `^T` for transpose -- are defined for the entire OS's text system in `/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/StandardKeyBinding.dict`.

To override the shortcuts, Apple suggests:

> To customize bindings, you create a file named DefaultKeyBinding.dict in ~/Library/KeyBindings/ and specify bindings to augment or replace the standard bindings. You may use the standard bindings file as a template. It is recommended that you use the Property List Editor application to edit a bindings dictionary. You may use another application such as TextEdit or Xcode, but if you do you must ensure the encoding of the saved file is UTF8.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html